# How to solve circular permutation from its linear analogue?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose I know how to solve a linear permutation problem, is there any general strategy to solve its circular analogue?

I apologise for putting multiple questions. The specific answers to these questions might be already available. I am **not** looking forward to the answers of these questions, rather , I want to know the common strategy (not manual counting) that all of these problems have.

1. Circular permutation of $n$ distinct objects: We can break the circle from $n$ places, each yielding its own linear arrangement, so $k \times n = n! \implies k = (n-1)!$
2. Consider $n$ sided polygon. How many $r$ sided polygon can be formed so that no sides are common? :  [image: circ_per] $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r = n-r$ and $x_i ≥ 1$. Therefore, number of possible ways is ${{n-r-1} \choose {r-1}} \color{red}{\frac{n}{r}}$
3. The number of ways in which a necklace can be formed using 6 identical diamonds and 3 identical pearls is: Partition $6$ into $3$ unordered tuples, i.e.,
   $(0,0,6),$ $(0,1,5),(0,2,4),(0,3,3),$ $(1,1,4),(1,2,3),(2,2,2)$. So, there are $7$ possibilities.

In problem (2) , I understood why ${{n-r-1} \choose {r-1}}$ is used, but I had a doubt on why $\color{red}{\frac{n}{r}}$ is used. We cannot apply the logic of problem (1) here since there is a lot of symmetry. Also, we cannot apply the logic of problem (2) to problem (3), as we get ${{6+3-1} \choose {3-1}} \times \frac{9}{3}$ which does not match with the correct answer $7$.

Is there any common strategy to all these problems?

Comment: In the second problem, are the $n$ vertices of the polygon labeled?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig No, the vertices are not labelled, I just wanted to show the number of vertices.

Comment: All of these are (I think) examples of enumeration of the orbits of a set under a group action (specifically under the action of a cyclic group) and Burnside's lemma / Redfield--Polya theory is the correct general framework for this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any common strategy to all these problems?

I think no, but I think that (2) and (a generalization of) (3) can be solved using the followings :

(I) The number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_r=n$ is $\binom{n+r-1}{n}$.

(II) The number of positive integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_r=n$ is $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$.

---

*A solution for (2)* :

Let us cut an edge of the $n$ sided polygon, and call the leftmost and the rightmost vertex $L,R$ respetively. It is impossible that both $L$ and $R$ are the vertices of $r$ sided polygon.

- If $L$ is the vertex of $r$ sided polygon and $R$ is not, then the number of such $r$ sided polygons is equal to the number of positive integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_r=n-r$. (Your nice drawing should be helpful.)
- If $R$ is the vertex of $r$ sided polygon and $L$ is not, then the number of such $r$ sided polygons is equal to the number of positive integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_r=n-r$.
- If $L,R$ are not the vertices of $r$ sided polygon, then the number of such $r$ sided polygons is equal to the number of positive integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_{\color{red}{r+1}}=n-r$. (Note that this has to be the sum of $r+1$ positive integers because $L,R$ are not the vertices of $r$ sided polygon.)

Therefore, the answer is
$$2\binom{n-r-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-r-1}{r}=\frac nr\binom{n-r-1}{r-1}$$

---

> 3. The number of ways in which a necklace can be formed using 6 identical diamonds and 3 identical pearls is: Partition $6$ into $3$ unordered tuples, i.e.,
>    $(0,0,6),$ $(0,1,5),(0,2,4),(0,3,3),$ $(1,1,4),(1,2,3),(2,2,2)$. So, there are $7$ possibilities.

(3) is about the number of partitions of $6$ into at most $3$ parts.

(**Added 1** : In (3), there is a word "necklace". There are two types of necklace. One is "turnover (or free) necklace", accepting all rotation/mirroring as identical. The other is "fixed necklace" without accepting them as identical. Now, the solution of (3) suggests that the necklaces in (3) are turnover necklaces since the solution does not count $(1,3,2)$ as a different necklace from $(1,2,3)$.)

(**Added 2** : I deleted the sentence "(3) is about the number of partitions of $n$ into at most $r$ parts" because I realized it is false for $r\geqslant 4$. Sorry for the confusion. However, it is true that (3) is about the number of partitions of $6$ into at most $3$ parts. Moreover, if the question says "$n$ identical diamonds and $3$ identical pearls", then it is about the number of partitions of $n$ into at most $3$ parts. So, the claim below works.)

**Claim** : The number of partitions of $n$ into at most $3$ parts is $\left\lfloor \dfrac{n^2+6n+13}{12}\right\rfloor$. $\ $([A001399](https://oeis.org/A001399))

*Proof of the claim* :

Let $A$ be the number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ with $x_1\lt x_2\lt x_3$.

Let $B$ be the number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ with $x_1=x_2\lt x_3$ or $x_1\lt x_2=x_3$.

Let $C$ be the number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ with $x_1=x_2=x_3$.

Then, we want to find $A+B+C$.

The number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ is $\binom{n+2}{2}$.

The number of non-negative integer solutions of $2x_4+x_5=n$ is $\begin{cases}\frac n2+1&\text{if $n\equiv 0\pmod 2$}
\\\frac{n+1}{2}&\text{if $n\equiv 1\pmod 2$}\end{cases}$, i.e. $\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil$.

The number of non-negative integer solutions of $3x_6=n$ is $\begin{cases}0&\text{if $n\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$}
\\1&\text{if $n\equiv 0\pmod 3$}\end{cases}$, i.e. $\left\lfloor\frac{2(n-1)}{3}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor$.

Since we have $$\begin{cases}\displaystyle\binom{n+2}{2}=3!A+3B+C
\\\\\left\lceil\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil=B+C
\\\\\left\lfloor\dfrac{2(n-1)}{3}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\dfrac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor=C\end{cases}$$
$A+B+C$ is equal to

$$\frac{1}{6}\bigg(\binom{n+2}{2}+3\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil+2\left\lfloor\frac{2(n-1)}{3}\right\rfloor-4\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor\bigg)\tag4$$

Considering $n=6m+r$ with $0\leqslant r\leqslant 5$, we see that $(4)$ can be simplified as $\left\lfloor \dfrac{n^2+6n+13}{12}\right\rfloor$.$\ \ \blacksquare$

Comment: Yes, but in (3), why exactly is that situation equivalent to number of partitions?

Comment: @S Das : I added some explanations. See **Added 1** and **Added 2**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *general analogue* that you seek.

Type $1$ is the simplest, and the approach is  widely known even to beginners.

Type $3$ is the most complex due to multiple colors/ symmetries and requires the use of [Burnside's Lemma /Polya's Enumeration Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics))

Type $2$ is an intermediate difficulty problem in which stars and bars or variants that essentially amount to  stars and bars can be used.

To clear up the point in the solution that is bothering you:

Between the $r$ points of the polygon we want, are $r$ "compartments" in which the remaining (n−r) points
can be placed, in $\binom{n−r-1}{r-1}$ ways.

And due to the circular type of arrangement, each pattern will repeat $r$ times, that is why the final answer is $\binom{n-r-1}{r-1}\times \frac{n}{r}$